# How to Highlight colour of specific row in Data table in Prime React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, primereact

I want to highlight colour of row which have the username "Bret".

Something like this => https://yourimageshare.com/ib/AxZUw6Vuo0

I have searched about this and tried with rowClassName,but none of the method is working. Can you please help me with the same?

Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-56mh8j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use `rowClassName` to highlight `Glenna` the user.

https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-56mh8j?

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I made one mistake in the syntax. Thank you so much for quick reply. Marking your answer as accepted.